# What would make winged centaurs a reasonable fighting force?

Tags: warfare, fantasy-races, ancient-history, tactics

Within my world of Astarious, I have a race known as the Pegtauri, winged centaurs, who for a time were feared raiders on villages near the mountains that separated their plains from the rest of civilization. But as they were barely-connected bands of wandering tribal herds, they were overwhelmed by the Norromans (Romans that conquered and ended up adopting elements of Nordic society and warfare) and enslaved.

Generations later though, groups of them escape Norroman enslavement along with some humans and halflings to form a Spartacus type rebellion. I have it that they win though, partially through deceit and sabotage by their chief spies the Arcani (a group of cat people that Norroman patricians enslaved then trained and 'bred' to be ninja like spies and assassins, who see the opportunity to overthrow their own masters, partially from Norroman corruption and greed) and also from the Pegtauri along with their new Partner Riders being a force to be reckoned with now that they're united, driven, and have some training from the Norromans forcing some of them into being gladiators and mounts for aerial cavalry.

My vision is for them to have Mongolian/Scythian like tactics, where they can feint and head away while the rider is able to continually shoot arrows or both fire in tandem, then also be able to have aerial advantages for dropping flechette like missiles down for a 'shower bombing' along with the regular arrows and missiles. However, it was pointed out to me that they would be rather large targets up in the air. And while the Norromans themselves wouldn't tend to be great archers, they would have auxiliary units that would have that training.

How do I make my Pegtauri more viable as a fighting force?

Comment: Can't they just fly higher than enemy arrows?

Comment: I suggest that you skip the backstory as it is not relevant to the question.  What is needed is some information on the physical and (presumably) magical weapons available to the combatants and the forces available to each side.  We also have no idea of the Pegtauri's abilities - how does their running ability compare to a horse, how far and how quickly can they fly?

Comment: Overwhelming and enslaving highly mobile nomadic peoples who can fly when the would-be enslavers cannot seems kinda impractical. The supply lines of the invaders are gonna get wrecked, and the offensive will fail or starve almost immediately. You may have heard the advice to never start a land war in asia. It is even more unwise to start an _air_ war in asia when you don't actually have anti-air weaponry.

Comment: To reinforce the @StarfishPrime comment: it's well nigh impossible for a 2D creature to capture **and enslave** a 3D creature that can just **fly away**.

Comment: Your shower bombs have a (quite terrifying) [real life version](https://military-history.fandom.com/wiki/Lazy_Dog_(bomb)).

Comment: Perhaps tangential, but if you spend any time researching low-fantasy, plausible-under-real-physics Pegasi, you will quickly reach the conclusion that it _just isn't possible_ (at least not without significantly changing the common conception of what a pegasus/centaur is).  Since your flying centaurs are going to have hand-wavingly magical flight anyway, if you want to give them supernatural speed/strength/stealth/whatever, you're really not changing the fundamentals of your world at all.

Answer (score 20):

**They can Fly**

I don't think you appreciate how much an advantage that is.

Bridge destroyed? Rough Terrain? Quagmire from too much rain? Dangerous mountain path? Nope - they can fly.

Castle walls? Nope - they can fly.

Almost all of our fortifications against infantry are predicated on the fact that the average soldier cannot fly. We only have to worry about movement in a mostly 2D space (with the exception of climbing/Rappelling).

In addition - the speed of flight is generally higher than the speed of movement on foot. Typical cruising speeds for birds are 26 - 45 kph - to put into perspective, the fastest Horse gallop was 89 Kph, but most horses are around 55 Kph - and they can only maintain a gallop for a short period of time.

That gives you speed and mobility - you get to dictate how and when you want to fight. Get surprised and in a bad position? Just fly away - they can't pursue you on foot and you can out-fly them.

Spot a weak flank? You can move to engage in a much shorter time than a conventional army can.

This is before we get to what is probably the single greatest advantage:

**Reconnaissance and message running**

Birds-eye-view - think of it like a Medieval U2 or SR-71 spy plane - you can go up high and see exactly what the Enemy is doing from kilometres away - see a big army on the march? You've got plenty of warning to counter. Need to alert your rear echolons of an attempted flank? No worries.

Now - sure, Archers pose a threat, but above a distance of about 100-200 metres (and I'm being generous here) they are no threat to a flying creature.

A sentient flying enemy without access to firearms is a terrifying combatant just on their ability to fly alone.

Comment: And to get anywhere near that 100-200 meter top range (as you say, pretty generous), you're firing in an arc at a target that far away, where gravity is responsible for preserving much of the force of the shot. Firing straight up means 1) Gravity doesn't help at all, halving the range and then some, because an arrow at the top of its arc has no force left to do damage to something above it, and 2) If you miss, the arrow is going to hit someone on the ground near you, e.g. one of your allies, with meaningful force. I doubt the strongest longbowmen would pose much of a threat even 50 meters up.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - Completely agree - I was thinking though that with such a threat, people might develop crossbows or use some form of Ballista that could get up higher than a standard arrow - but as I said - 'Being generous'

Comment: @ShadowRanger Longbow's arrows have speed of around 50 m/s. So in one second of flight they reach the height of 45 m with the remaining speed of 40 m/s. So 50 meters up the target wouldn't be all that hard to hit, and at that speed the arrow would still be lethal. With poisoned tips, where just breaking the skin would be dangerous, an arrow 4 seconds in flight would have ending speed of 10 m/s at the height of 120 m (probably max range).
That doesn't take into account possible advancement in the weapons tech. Crossbows and curved bows can get higher speeds and be thus better for this purpose.

Comment: @Negdo shooting a moving target in the air is very much a non-trivial exercise even if you had the opportunity to practise, which will be challenging in itself. Volley-firing poison arrows upwards sounds like a tactic that's eventually going to result in an epic self-own which will surely be remembered through the ages as people try to work out why you didn't see the obvious catastrophe coming.

Answer (score 12):

***Frame Challenge: The question should not be what makes them useful, but what you need to do to keep them from being too useful.***

### Understanding the relationship between horse archers and the Roman army

The Romans were able to counter Mongolian/Scythian tactics only because they fielded thier own cavalry.  While a disciplined Roman Legion could take a shower of arrows from an army of eastern horse archers with relatively few losses, the only reason they ever beat such enemies was because they had heavy cavalry.  Horse archers can ride and shoot, but they could not ride at full speed and shoot meaning that a heavy cavalry charge could catch up to them, and when that would happen, the unit cohesion, and melee focused armaments of the Roman cavalry would generally win out.

At the Battle of the Catalaunian Plains for example, the Huns could not retreat fast enough to avoid the Roman lead cavalry charge, and Attila lost so many of his horse archers that he was forced to abandon his war on Europe.

The reason this is important is because if the Norromans don't have flying units of thier own to battle the Pegtauri, they will never be able to close range and fight the Pegtauri like the Romans could with the Huns.  Instead it will end more like the Battle of Carrhae where the Romans were just skirmished to death in one of thier most 1-sided military defeats.

### Why Archers can't counter Pegtauri

The problem with archers here is that elevation matters a LOT.  So, even if you had the best bows and archers in the world, they would be useless against the Pegtauri.

A top tier longbow has a firing velocity of 53m/s.  Assuming a 90 degree firing angle, this tops out at ~144m at ~5.3 seconds of flight time... but this is a grossly impractical statistic because the human body is not designed to bring a longbow to full draw at this angle.  The steepest angle you can fully draw a longbow is about 45 degrees.  Higher than this, and the only way to achieve a full draw length is to pull with your triceps instead of your much stronger shoulder and back muscles making a high pound bow WAY too hard to draw at steeper angles, even for top athletes.

Fired at 45 degrees, a 53m/s arrow maxes out at a height of ~73m after ~3.8 seconds of flight time at a range of 214m... but again, this assumes that the Pegtauri are just flying in a straight line at a trajectory that will perfectly intersect this exact range and distance and that your archer is target perfect at that range... but that is not a reasonable assumption.  In practice, "target accuracy" will require firing at Pegtauri that are less than 2 seconds of flight time away.  This means altitudes of ~56m or less.

However, the Pegtauri have the high ground; so, thier arrows are sped up by gravity, not slowed down.  Using a similar bow, they can from an altitude of 90m fire an arrow 45 degrees down striking a target in 2 seconds giving them target accuracy from above the ground archer's theoretical maximum altitude.

### Why you can't catch the Pegtauri on the ground

> forcing some of them into being gladiators and mounts for aerial calvary

This little statement mean that the Pegtauri MUST have excellent flying endurance and lift capacity.  If Pegtauri can fly with a rider at all, it means that they can fly very well without a rider.  This writes you out of any possible explanation that they have to land and rest often.  It also means that the Pegtauri, without a rider, can spare the weight for some decent armor, a very large number of arrows, or some heavier anti-armor projectiles if they so desire.

### Conclusion: The Norromans Need either Guns or Flying units.

So, the only way this works out in any way that is not totally one sided is if the Norromans have a way to strike back.

One solution is to give them some other flying units. It could be thier own Pegtauri regiments who did not defect. Or maybe an alternate flying mount like gryphons or dragons... or heck, it could even be something as simple as falcons who are trained to peck the eyes out of the Pegtauri.

The other solution would be to give them guns.  Guns, even primative ones, fire much higher velocities than bows meaning shooting up is less of a problem for them.  A musket that is target accurate at 150m horizontally will still be close to target accurate when fired up... plus, they are better at aiming up at greater than 45 degrees when they need to.

Whatever the case may be, the Norromans need something that can meet the Pegtauri in the sky with or they will with 100% certainty, be screwed beyond belief.

Comment: A good nerf for the Pegtauri would be stamina. They have to lift the weight of a horse up into the air. This will burn massive amounts of energy (handwaving the physics of wings, which would make it impossible in earths atmosphere without magic) - If the Pegtauri are quickly exhausted after flying for a few minutes (which would also explain, why they need 4 legs/hooves, because they usually run/gallop) you would need smart tactics to use their advantage, without making them easy targets once they have to land nearby.

Comment: @Falco I considered this, but If a Pegtauri  can carry a rider, even for a short while as the OP dictates, then it can fly itself, and a bow and arrow for a considerable distance.

Comment: You are right - if they really can carry a rider while flying long distances, they are crazy overpowered.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Longbow's arrows have speed of around 50 m/s. So in one second of flight they reach the height of 45 m with the remaining speed of 40 m/s. So 50 meters up the target wouldn't be all that hard to hit, and at that speed the arrow would still be lethal.

Comment: @Negdo I've expanded my answer explaining why archers have such a short effective ceiling.  I also removed the bit about minimum speed though since I was not considering the lateral velocity of the arrow + the flight speed of the Pegtauri when I said that part.